# ng-repeat to produce stars in efficient way of a song's rating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing an app in Angular JS. My HTML code is like below,

**index.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr ng-repeat="music in musicTracks" ng-click="showValue(music)">
                            <td><strong>{{music.name}}</strong><br/>
                            <span><h6>Genre: {{music.genre}}</h6></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" ng-repeat="star in music.stars"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" ng-repeat="star in music.noStars"></span> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

and there is an array in my `app.controller` like below,

```
$scope.musicTracks = [
        {"id":1,"name": "Tum hi Ho", "genre": "bollywood", "stars":[0,1,2,3,4], "noStars": []},
        {"id":2,"name": "Djwale Babu", "genre": "pop", "stars":[0,1,2], "noStars": [0,1]},
        {"id":3,"name": "Into the bluws", "genre": "hollywood", "stars":[0,1,2,3], "noStars": [0]}
    ]
```

Is there any way to achieve the same thing efficiently/ without using two arrays namely `stars` and `noStars` ?

My output will be like following,

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

try like this.Beacaus the length all stars is 5 so you can create array with this length. now repeat stars and check $index with count of stars and change  class to `glyphicon glyphicon-star`or `glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty` base its condition.

```
$scope.starArray = new Array(5);
$scope.musicTracks = [
    {"id":1,"name": "Tum hi Ho", "genre": "bollywood", "stars":5}
]
```

**in view**

```
<span ng-repeat="star in starArray track by $index" 
      ng-class="(music.stars > $index) ? 
     'glyphicon glyphicon-star' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty'" >
</span>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0TXKrl0EWuRygIu18V0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you don't even need an array for stars, just a number. since you're doing it out of 5 use the range.

```
<span ng-class="(n <= music.stars.length)? 'glyphicon glyphicon-star' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty'" ng-repeat="n in range(1,5)">
```